# hdparm - version that accepts non-ascii characters for ata passwords

Tags: hard-drive, password

I'm looking for a way of using `hdparm` to unlock my drive.

Simple enough you would think once you have the password?

Nope, the password, thanks dell, contain non-ascii characters.

I have the password in hex, so `$(print '\x2e\x20' )` shows up in hdparm as something like

```
password = 'squiggle no closing to the '
```

So is there a version of hdparm i can use ?
maybe one that accepts a file for the password perhaps?

or even the instructions on how to download source hdparm & a diff file for the changes I need to make to the security commands to allow file usage ?
oh and then how to erm build/make/replace/use the new hdparm (renamed?)

a guide of some variety would be great, as although I have some idea of what i am doing, it takes ages to google for the 'little steps' that a *nix user 'just should know'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve here but this command:

```
hdparm --security-unlock $(printf '\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20\x57\x6F\x72\x6C\x64') /dev/sdc
```

would send the listed hexadecimal values from the printf command to hdparm and should produce

> security_password="Hello World"
>
> /dev/sdc:
>
> Issuing SECURITY_UNLOCK command, password="Hello World", user=user

Is this what you want? If not, you can put just about anything in the brackets to translate from any base to any other. No need to use a different version of hdparm, less still to compile from source.